# How to create object of class from client project

Tags: c#, class, silverlight, object, namespaces

When we create a Silverlight application, which includes two projects. The Silverlight project and the web project. I have a class in my `SilverlightApplication1.Web` namespace and I am trying to create an object of that class in my `MainPage.xaml.cs` class which is present in `SilverlightApplication1` namespace.
But seems like I can't create an object of the web project from the Silverlight project. How can I do this? What's the concept?

When I create object I get error:

> The type or namespace could not be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your Silverlight project doesn't have a reference to the web project. That's probably a good thing, mind you - I would suggest you set up a *third* project (as a Silverlight class library) called "Common" or something similar, and make both the web project and the Silverlight project refer to that. Put types which aren't web-specific or Silverlight-specific in that project, and then you can use them from both the web and Silverlight projects.

Comment: Isn't there any way I can `Add a Reference` of  the `Web` Project in my `Silverlight` Project? I tried by `Add Reference->Solutions->Projects` but got error `You can only add project references to other Silverlight projects in the solution`

Comment: @HumaAli: Well that seems fairly self-explanatory. I suspect you'll need to create a Silverlight class library, but you *should* be able to add a reference to that from your web app, I believe. That makes sense, as your web app could be using all kinds of web-server-specific things that don't exist in Silverlight.

Comment: You are right. I have created many class files in Web project that I want to reference from Silverlight Project. So does this mean I have to create a class Library and move all those `.cs` files into it so that the Silverlight Project can reference it?

Comment: @HumaAli: Yes, exactly a per my answer. (Also please note that the code font in Stack Overflow should be used for things which are really code. Using it for terms like "class library" makes comments hard to read - that's why I edited your question, too.)

Comment: Edited my comment :)